# Update table in access by joining a table from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using access and sql server combined. My main tables are housed in sql server, and my temp tables are created in access.  I am trying to update a temp table in access by joining a table from sql server.  But i keep getting the error, operation must use an updateable query. Here is my query below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2] INNER JOIN dbo_Indicator_0 ON ([tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_allow = dbo_Indicator_0.cpt_code_allow) AND ([tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_omit = dbo_Indicator_0.cpt_code_omit) SET [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag = On
WHERE ((([tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag)=Off));
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you create temporary tables in SQL Server?

Comment: I could do that but I was using access as the front end. I could just use a pass through query to create the tables in sql server, would this fix the error that I am having

Comment: I would suggest changing the whole architecture to use SQL Server.  It is a more powerful database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE dbo_Indicator_0 
INNER JOIN 
[tmpEditErrCode220 - 2] ON ([dbo_Indicator_0].cpt_code_omit = [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_omit) AND ([dbo_Indicator_0].cpt_code_allow = [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_allow) 
SET [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag = "On"
WHERE ((([tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag)="off"));
```

Comment: stilll receive the error operation must use an updateable query

Comment: Please confirm that  [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2] has a Primary Key.  Please confirm that  [dbo_Indicator_0] has a Primary Key.

Comment: neither of these tables have primary keys, as there are duplicate values

Comment: I'm confident that adding a primary key to each table, to ensure at least minimal indexing is done, will solve the problem.

Comment: If more than one `[dbo_Indicator_0]` row can match a `[tmpEditErrCode220 - 2]` row, Access will not consider the query to be updatable.

Comment: Sounds right.  And if [cpt_code_omit] and [dbo_Indicator_0] are both Primary Keys (or Indexed No Duplicates) it should work.

Comment: this query works though if all tables are housed in access though without primary keys

Comment: OK good, that's encouraging.  Access is probably imposing a constraint on the sql server table, that the join be to a primary key. Access does treat certain kinds of linked tables a little differently.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this constraint.  I need the tables housed in sql server as some of the tables are over millions of lines.  Also I have to have duplicates. Basically I am checking to see if a code is billable.

Comment: Did you try setting the linked field in sql server to Indexed.

Comment: OK I was able to do this by just creating the temp tables through a pass through query into sql server and dropping the table after use without using primary keys. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: ok good.  creating an temporary intermediary table is the next last-ditch thing I was going to suggest.  it's not elegant but always solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tmpEditErrCode220
SET [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag = "On"
FROM [dbo_Indicator_0] 
WHERE [dbo_Indicator_0].cpt_code_omit = [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_omit 
AND [dbo_Indicator_0].cpt_code_allow = [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].cpt_code_allow 
WHERE [tmpEditErrCode220 - 2].flag = "Off";
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**